# How to create an array of arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c

Using plain c, if I have the following two arrays:

```
WCHAR depthUnits[2][10] = { _T("feet"), _T("metres") };
WCHAR speedUnits[3][10] = { _T("ft/min"), _T("m/min"), _T("m/s") };
```

How can I create an array called say allUnits and fill it with the above so that it will behave like so:

```
allUnits[0][0] = "feet";
allUnits[0][1] = "metres";
allUnits[1][0] = "ft/min";
allUnits[1][1] = "m/min";
allUnits[1][2] = "m/s";
```

So basically allUnits is an array and each element of that array is itself an array such that allUnits[0] references depthUnits and allUnits[1] references speedUnits.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use dynamic memory allocation then you should allocate an array of pointers, then for each pointer, allocate another array (of the type you need) and assign the pointer to the corresponding index in the first array. If you work on the stack or on global memory, then I think you should use a 2D array.

Comment: @SomethingSomething No. What OP needs is an of pointers to char[10]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for an array of pointers to array of 10 char. Further you want the array to have 2 elements.

That would be like:

```
WCHAR (*allUnits[2])[10];
allUnits[0] = depthUnits;
allUnits[1] = speedUnits;
```

An example using `char` instead of `WCHAR`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char depthUnits[2][10] = {"feet", "metres" };
    char speedUnits[3][10] = {"ft/min", "m/min", "m/s" };
    
    char (*allUnits[2])[10];
    allUnits[0] = depthUnits;
    allUnits[1] = speedUnits;
    
    puts(allUnits[0][0]);
    puts(allUnits[0][1]);
    puts(allUnits[1][0]);
    puts(allUnits[1][1]);
    puts(allUnits[1][2]);

    // Change feet -> Feet using depthUnits
    depthUnits[0][0] = 'F';
    
    // See that it also changed allUnits
    puts(allUnits[0][0]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
feet
metres
ft/min
m/min
m/s
Feet
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. It enabled me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
WCHAR *allUnits[2][3];

/* ... */

allUnits[0][0] = depthUnits[0];
allUnits[0][1] = depthUnits[1];
allUnits[1][0] = speedUnits[0];
allUnits[1][1] = speedUnits[1];
allUnits[1][2] = speedUnits[2];
```

Answer (score -1):

This uses array initialization, maybe that's what you wanted:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char* allUnits[][3] = {
    {"feet", "meters"},
    {"ft/min", "m/min", "m/sec"}
  };

  printf("0 0: %s\n", allUnits[0][0]);
  printf("0 1: %s\n", allUnits[0][1]);
  printf("1 0: %s\n", allUnits[1][0]);
  printf("1 1: %s\n", allUnits[1][1]);
  printf("1 2: %s\n", allUnits[1][2]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize an array of arrays like you would any other array.

```c
WCHAR* depthUnits[] = { _T("feet"), _T("metres") };
WCHAR* speedUnits[] = { _T("ft/min"), _T("m/min"), _T("m/s") };
WCHAR** allUnits[] = { depthUnits, speedUnits };
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their replies. This one (from Wyck) would best suit my needs but it's not working for me. Maybe I'm accessing wrongly? So, for instance, if I want to access "feet" I tried allUnits[0][0] like so:WCHAR szCopy[MAXLONGDSETNAMECHARPLUSONE];
 wcsncpy_s(szCopy, MAXLONGDSETNAMECHARPLUSONE, allUnits[0][0], MAX_PATH); but that gives a crash.

Comment: It's because this one is wrong. **Wyck** made a mistake

Comment: @gnitsuk it is technically an error to combine `_T` and `WCHAR` (But I was just following your lead though).  You should be using `_T` and `_TCHAR` if you want to be able to compile your source code for both Unicode builds and non-Unicode (ANSI string) builds.  Is that your problem?  Is it a compiler settings problem?

Comment: @Dúthomhas what was my mistake?  Why is it wrong?

Comment: Heh, it looks like _I_ made a mistake. I should really learn to slow down when looking at code on the internet. Sorry. Upvoted!